# Oversampling functionality in Tensorflow dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, sampling, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to ask if current API of datasets allows for implementation of oversampling algorithm? I deal with highly imbalanced class problem. I was thinking that it would be nice to oversample specific classes during dataset parsing i.e. online generation. I've seen the implementation for rejection_resample function, however this removes samples instead of duplicating them and its slows down batch generation (when target distribution is much different then initial one). The thing I would like to achieve is: to take an example, look at its class probability decide if duplicate it or not. Then call `dataset.shuffle(...)` `dataset.batch(...)` and get iterator. The best (in my opinion) approach would be to oversample low probable classes and subsample most probable ones. I would like to do it online since it's more flexible.

Comment: You should accept your answer :)

Answer (score 14):

This problem has been solved in issue [#14451](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14451#event-1336837542).
Just posting the anwser here to make it more visible to other developers.

The sample code is oversampling low frequent classes and undersampling high frequent ones, where `class_target_prob` is just uniform distribution in my case. I wanted to check some conclusions from recent manuscript [A systematic study of the class imbalance problem in convolutional neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05381)

The oversampling of specific classes is done by calling:

```
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(oversample_classes(x))
)
```

Here is the full snippet which does all the things:

```
# sampling parameters
oversampling_coef = 0.9  # if equal to 0 then oversample_classes() always returns 1
undersampling_coef = 0.5  # if equal to 0 then undersampling_filter() always returns True

def oversample_classes(example):
    """
    Returns the number of copies of given example
    """
    class_prob = example['class_prob']
    class_target_prob = example['class_target_prob']
    prob_ratio = tf.cast(class_target_prob/class_prob, dtype=tf.float32)
    # soften ratio is oversampling_coef==0 we recover original distribution
    prob_ratio = prob_ratio ** oversampling_coef 
    # for classes with probability higher than class_target_prob we
    # want to return 1
    prob_ratio = tf.maximum(prob_ratio, 1) 
    # for low probability classes this number will be very large
    repeat_count = tf.floor(prob_ratio)
    # prob_ratio can be e.g 1.9 which means that there is still 90%
    # of change that we should return 2 instead of 1
    repeat_residual = prob_ratio - repeat_count # a number between 0-1
    residual_acceptance = tf.less_equal(
                        tf.random_uniform([], dtype=tf.float32), repeat_residual
    )

    residual_acceptance = tf.cast(residual_acceptance, tf.int64)
    repeat_count = tf.cast(repeat_count, dtype=tf.int64)

    return repeat_count + residual_acceptance


def undersampling_filter(example):
    """
    Computes if given example is rejected or not.
    """
    class_prob = example['class_prob']
    class_target_prob = example['class_target_prob']
    prob_ratio = tf.cast(class_target_prob/class_prob, dtype=tf.float32)
    prob_ratio = prob_ratio ** undersampling_coef
    prob_ratio = tf.minimum(prob_ratio, 1.0)

    acceptance = tf.less_equal(tf.random_uniform([], dtype=tf.float32), prob_ratio)

    return acceptance


dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(oversample_classes(x))
)

dataset = dataset.filter(undersampling_filter)

dataset = dataset.repeat(-1)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

### Update #1

Here is a simple [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/deep-learning-notes/tree/master/tf-oversampling) which implements the above oversampling/undersampling on a toy model.

Comment: can you please give an example of the contents of `dataset` in `dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(oversample_classes(x))
)` should look like?

Comment: Take a look on update in original post which I've added.

Comment: Thank you. The notebook was really helpful.

Comment: This is fantastic. There is no way I would have figured this out on my own. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Is this implementation comparable in speed to constructing tfrecords from oversampled data and then feeding it to Dataset API?

Comment: It will be slower in practice. Probably the biggest bottleneck is undersampling of highly frequent class in your dataset. In that case you must read tfrecord and then decide whether you keep or reject this class. This class will have high probability of being filtered out, so you will need to read another record to complete your mini-batch. Once you reject one example you must load the next one, which takes time. Note, this approach is more flexible and in some cases it may be more practical to do online sampling. You should make a benchmark and then decide which approach is better for you.

Comment: The problem is that dataset is usually read from tf_record file, which doesn't contain "class_pro" and "class_target_pro" attributes. It would be much more useful if it doesn't require to write new tfrecord file, otherwise why don't you oversample while writing new tfrecord file?

Comment: This is just a simple demo, and you can of course generate class_pro on fly. You would need a external dict with class_id -> class_pro mapping.

Answer (score 2):

[tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/rejection_resample) seems to be a better way, since it does not require "class_prob" and "class_target_prob" feature.
Although it is under-sampling instead of over-sampling, with the same target distribution and training steps, it would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

This QnA was so helpful for me. So I wrote a blog post about it with my related experience.

https://vallum.github.io/Optimizing_parallel_performance_of_resampling_with_tensorflow.html

I hope someone who is interested in Tensorflow input pipeline optimization with re-sampling might get some idea from it.

Some ops are probably unnecessarily redundant but were not too big performance degraders in my personal case.

```
 dataset = dataset.map(undersample_filter_fn, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls) 
 dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x : x)
```

flat_map with the identity lambda function is just for merging survived (and empty) records

```
# Pseudo-code for understanding of flat_map after maps
#parallel calls of map('A'), map('B'), and map('C')
map('A') = 'AAAAA' # replication of A 5 times
map('B') = ''      # B is dropped
map('C') = 'CC'    # replication of C twice
# merging all map results
flat_map('AAAA,,CC') = 'AAAACC'
```

Answer (score 0):

After trials and tribulations, here is a rough solution for the binary case. I split the dataset into two by label, then shuffled and repeated the smaller sub-dataset and concatenated them back together, taking only as many samples as needed. So, for a dataset with `x,y` attributes:

```
def _ds_is_batched(ds: tf.data.Dataset):
    # returns True iff the dataset is batched
    return hasattr(ds, '_batch_size') and ds._batch_size.numpy() > 1

def _get_ds_len(ds: tf.data.Dataset):
    # returns number of samples in the dataset
    n = 0
    _is_batched = _ds_is_batched(ds)
    for _ in ds:
        n += _[0].numpy().shape[0] if _is_batched else 1
    return n

def balance_ds(ds: tf.data.Dataset, shuffle_bs: int = 1000):
    # returns a new dataset with oversampling of the less-frequent class
    ds0 = ds.filter(lambda x, y, *args: tf.math.equal(y, 0))
    ds1 = ds.filter(lambda x, y, *args: tf.math.equal(y, 1))
    n0, n1 = _get_ds_len(ds0), _get_ds_len(ds1)
    # shuffle and repeat the less frequent class in order to oversample it
    if n0 < n1:
        ds0 = ds0.shuffle(shuffle_bs).repeat(int(np.ceil(n1/n0))).take(n1)
    else:
        ds1 = ds1.shuffle(shuffle_bs).repeat(int(np.ceil(n0 / n1))).take(n0)
    res = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds0, ds1])
    res = res.shuffle(shuffle_bs)
    return res
```