# How can I return the same batch twice from a tensorflow dataset iterator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am converting some legacy code to use the Dataset API - this code uses `feed_dict` to feed one batch to the train operation (actually three times) and then recalculates the losses for display *using the same batch*. So I need to have an iterator that returns the exact same batch two (or several) times. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way of doing it with tensorflow datasets - is it possible?

Comment: Turns out my usecase is a subcase of issue [#14451](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14451) - discussed here in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47236465/281545

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can repeat individual elements of a `Dataset` using [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map), [`Dataset.from_tensors()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors) and [`Dataset.repeat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) together. For example, to repeat elements twice:

```
NUM_REPEATS = 2
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)  # ...or the output of `.batch()`, etc.

# Repeat each element of `dataset` NUM_REPEATS times.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(NUM_REPEATS))
```