# Manually Get Next Batch or Use Identical Batch with TensorFlow Data API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the tf.Data API to accelerate my code and prevent GPU data starvation but there is one thing that is stopping me for being comfortable with it and it's the ability to use the same batch when calling the training op multiple times.

Suppose I have my dataset set up as

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("textfile.txt")
dataset = dataset.shuffle(dataset_size)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, ...)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x_batch = iterator.get_next()

loss1 = someFunctionOf(x_batch)
loss2 = someOtherFunctionOf(x_batch)
train_op1 = someOptimizerOf(loss1)
train_op2 = someOtherOptimizerOf(loss2)
```

but now whenever I call `train_op1`, `iterator.get_next()` is called and so when calling `train_op2`, I am training on the next batch.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358750/how-can-i-return-the-same-batch-twice-from-a-tensorflow-dataset-iterator) question, I am aware that I can use a combination of `flat_map` and `repeat(n)` where `n` is the number of times I wanna repeat the same batch but this `n` would depend on the number of `train_ops` that I call which I have to count manually. Also, I need these two `train_ops` because they optimize different parts of my graph.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. It creates a copy of input and target so hopefully they will not change when you switch optimizer/loss_op. They are persistent between `sess.run` calls as long as you do not pass `is_new:True` flag.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf


def ds_train(batch_size, num_epochs):  
    ds = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0], [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]))
            .batch(batch_size)
            .repeat(num_epochs)        
            )
    return ds


batch_size = 1
input_size = 1
num_epochs = 2

with tf.variable_scope("dataset"):       
    ds_t = ds_train(batch_size, num_epochs)

with tf.variable_scope("iterator"):
    iterator_t = ds_t.make_initializable_iterator()
    iterator_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[], name="iterator_handle")
    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(iterator_handle, 
                                                iterator_t.output_types,
                                                iterator_t.output_shapes)

    def next_item():
        next_elem = iterator.get_next(name="next_element")
        x, y = tf.cast(next_elem[0], tf.float32), next_elem[1]# tf.cast(next_elem[1], tf.int32)
        return x, y        


inputs = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size,input_size]), dtype=tf.float32, name="inputs", trainable=False, use_resource=True)
target = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32), dtype=tf.int32, name="target", trainable=False,use_resource=True)
is_new = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.constant(False), shape=[], name="new_item_flag")

def new_data(batch_size, input_size):
    # run the data layer to generate a new batch
    next_inputs, next_target = next_item()
    next_inputs = tf.reshape(next_inputs, shape=[batch_size, input_size])
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(inputs, next_inputs), tf.assign(target, next_target)]):
        return tf.identity(inputs), tf.identity(target)

def old_data():
    # just forward the existing batch
    return inputs, target

next_inputs, next_target = next_item()

inputs, target =  tf.cond(is_new, lambda:new_data(batch_size, input_size), old_data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer()])
    handle_t = sess.run(iterator_t.string_handle())
    sess.run(iterator_t.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle:handle_t, is_new: False}))
            print(sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle:handle_t, is_new: False}))
            print(sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle:handle_t, is_new: True}))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("End of training dataset.")
            break
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply. Your solution seems to work but it also seems to me to be more complicated than needed. I was trying to remove the StringHandler but it seems like this gave other problems. I was investigating that. There's also the problem that the first time, the returned batch is just zeros, as how was initialized the variables for inputs and target. This solution also does not work with variable batch size lengths, e.g. when we want to pad to different lengths in seq2seq models.

Comment: Variable batch size was not part of the question, so I have not investigated that.

Comment: Regarding string handler, that is just iterator type I prefer to use, but I guess one_shot_iterator or any other also should work. If the first returned batch is just zeros then call `sess.run[inputs, target]` once outside of the traninig loop.

Comment: Other than that if you think my post answers your question then please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I have to investigate a little more on using just a one shot iterator. Since right now I'm having problems with it, I could use this thread to post my problems too so I might want to close it only when I'm sure of everything.

Comment: That is not really how StackOverflow works. If you have new problem you should create new posts. People, including myself, will not want to read posts that get updated numerous times.